# Self-signed certificates in Java - Signing XML-files

Tags: java, xml, signature

I have a Java-application which collects data, writes it into an XML-file and sends this XML-file via mail. This application runs on many different computers (not within my scope). Then there is another application which takes the received XML-file and inserts the data into a database (this app runs on my own server). Until now I had to trust, that the data hasn't been changed and that the XML-file comes really from a trusted source.

Now I thought of signing the XML using Java-Keystore. What works until now is the following:

- I can create a key-pair using the keytool.
- Then I use the created private key to sign an XML-file using Java's XML Digital Signature API (http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/dig_signature_api/).
- I am also able to validate the signed file.

My problem is now, how to make sure the data is really from a trusted system. I mean, what I have done so far is simply making sure, that the data wasn't modified between the moment it was signed and the moment it is validated. What I want is to issue a certificate for every system that sends me data and only trust certificates issued by myself. But how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to become the CA (certificate authority) for your clients. Every client needs to provide their own client cert request to be signed by you, which they then use to sign each document before sending it.  This is the classic PKI management problem, which has spawned products which solve this more elegantly, but you'll have to pay for them.

Comment: Yes, that is also how I thought it would work. My problem is more that I don't know, how I can accept only certificates issued by myself, because in the code example of Sun the issuer of the certificate isn't checked. Also see the following quote of Sun which describes exactly my problem: "It is important to note that the XML signature standard does not define how the recipient establishes trust in the key that is needed to validate the signature. The KeyInfo element is merely a collection of information that the recipient can use to help find and subsequently establish trust in that key."